# Objective-C : Something that I don't understand with subclassing

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I don't understand something with subclassing in Objective-C : for example, we say that NSString inherits from NSObject, but does NSObject also inherits from NSString ?
I am wondering this because when I create a new class that inherits from NSObject, I have also access to NSString even if my class doesn't inherits from NSString.
For example, I can write this in my class that inherits form NSObject :

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello world !"];
```

And what I don't understand is that I can do this even if NSString is a subclass of NSObject and not it's superclass ! !

Comment: What do you mean you have access to NSString?

Comment: @Jeff I mean that I can write :
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello world !"]; 
And what I don't understand is that I can do this even if NSString is a subclass of NSObject and not it's superclass !

Comment: That's the whole point of OOP, to be able to access other objects from your objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you can access NSString is because you gave to import Foundation. 
Foundation includes NSObject and NSProxy the two public base classes provided in it. 
You pretty much need all of Foundation to have a viable Objective-C library unless you are implementing your own from the ground up. Then you would have a lot of work to do.

The same is true in C or other languages. The language implementation provides some core standard libraries that give you a basis to work with.

Some parts are actually macros some are functions. Some are common essential objects

Answer (score 3):

When you call this:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello world !"];
```

You are sending `stringWithFormat:` to `NSString`, which defines it as a static method (or for better terms, a class method). It has nothing to do with the superclass of your class. You are mixing up basic concept of objective C and OOP in general. Subclassing means inheriting the 'traits' of the original class, and eventually extend its functionality. It does not mean that you can't call other class' methods.

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding subclassing.

`stringWithFormat:` is a static method (class method) on `NSString`. You can create objects of other classes within a subclass (providing you have the necessary imports), but you cannot access methods on your class, unless it is a subclass and inherits the method, or defines the method itself.

e.g.

```
YourClass *testClass;

[testClass testMethod:@"Test"];
```

This would fail, unless `testClass` inherited from a class that defined `testMethod:`, or defined it itself.

Answer (score 0):

I am a complete beginner to Objective-C programming and in fact I was confused by this :
I read that in theory, a subclass is inheriting from the methods from its superclass and not the contrary, so I just thought that if I was able to access to NSString in a class that was a subclass from NSObject, it meant that NSObject was in fact accessing to the NSString methods (which wasn't logic since NSString is a subclass of NSObject).

**Finally, I just realized that if I was able to access to NSString, it was ONLY because of the "inclusion" of Fundation.h in my header with :**

```
#import <Fundation/Fundation.h>
```